# Magento 2: Translate This is a required field

Tags: magento2, inline-translations, js-translation

I'm already having a lot of trouble translating some Magento 2 texts, but I really can't seem figure this one out. I'm trying to translate the "This is a required field." text to Dutch. I already tried editing it in my nl_NL.csv, in which other texts are being translated as well. I deployed, cleared my cache, removed my pub/static folder, all of which do not give me a result.

How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: You need to modify core JS file.

Comment: This text is non translatable. If your store is not multilingual you can change the text in the validation.js file. (This is not recommended though). You can override the function in rules.js in your theme at this path : app/designVendor/themename/Magento_Ui/web/js/lib/validation/‌​rules.js

Answer (score -1):

To revive an old question with one of possibly many solutions, the text can be translated through a custom JavaScript file. Within this file you can override / apply the same validation rule as the existing `required-entry` rule and pass it a translation.

To do this you need the following:

**web/js/translations.js**

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/translate'
], function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'required-entry', function (value) {
                return (value !== '');
            }, $.mage.__('This is a required field.'));
    })
});
```

**require.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'translations': 'js/translations'
        }
    }
};
```

**i18n/nl_NL.csv**

```
"This is a required field.", "Dit is een verplicht veld"
```

I hope this helps people who, like me, ran into this problem.

Comment: Hey @Mike, Can you be a bit more specific on where to put the files? Might be obvious for you, but I have no idea.